# Android Gradle Exception: "Multiple dex files define", duplicated classes under exploded-aar

Tags: java, android, maven, gradle, aar

I'm trying to use my *aar-library* (a maven project, built with the *android-maven-plugin* by Jayway) in a gradle project but, when I run `gradle assembleDebug`, I'm having the following exception:

```
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define   Lcom/google/android/gms/actions/ItemListIntents;
at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:596)
at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:554)
at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:535)
at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:171)
at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:502)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:334)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:277)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:245)
at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
```

If I search that class in my project, Android Studio finds two results:

- `ListItemIntents (com.google.android.gms.action)   play-services-base-7.0.0(classes.jar)`
- `ListItemIntents (com.google.android.gms.action)   aar-library(classes.jar)`

Running the inspection 
`gradle dependencyInsight --dependency play-services-base --configuration compile` I get:

```
com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:7.0.0
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:7.0.0
|    \--- aar-library:core:1.0.10-SNAPSHOT
|         \--- compile                
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:7.0.0
|    \--- com.nexse.mobile.betting.core:core:1.0.10-SNAPSHOT (*)
\--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:7.0.0
     \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:7.0.0 (*)

(*) - dependencies omitted (listed previously)
```

The problem is in *aar-library* `classes.jar`: `ListIntentIntents` (and, obviously, the whole *play-services-base* module) is already there! So inside

```
my-gradle-project/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/
```

I have two references of *play-services-base* module: one under `com.google.android.gms` folder, one under `aar-library` folder

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the culprit! I was using the old *android maven plugin*                 `com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2`

The new one `com.simpligility.maven.plugins` fixed the error.

Anyway thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You may try including multidex enable true in your gradle file as follows:

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 22
buildToolsVersion "23.0.0"

     defaultConfig {
         minSdkVersion 14 //lower than 14 doesn't support multidex
         targetSdkVersion 22

         // Enabling multidex support.
         multiDexEnabled true
     }
}
```

Comment: First of all thank you for your response.

That doesn't seem to work:

`:app:packageAllDebugClassesForMultiDex FAILED
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:packageAllDebugClassesForMultiDex'.
> java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/actions/ItemListIntents.class`

However, my app has 8 as minSdkVersion, so I'd rather not follow that path.

Answer (score 0):

> If the number of method references in your app exceeds the 65K limit,
>   your app may fail to compile. You may be able to mitigate this problem
>   when compiling your app by specifying only the specific Google Play
>   services APIs your app uses, instead of all of them.

Above statements are taken from https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup.

**First :** Click on `Clean Project` from `Build` Item in menu bar (Android Studio).

**Second :** Try adding individual dependencies. Example If you only want to use Location services then only add `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:7.8.0'` in your `build.gradle`.